# SPARQL - Filter wikidata identifiers

Tags: wikidata, linked-data, sparql, semantic-web

Query below gives me all programming languages entities, with their statements.

Problem is that I don't need identifiers now, but these IDs might become necessary. I was just gonna model database return with toJSON, but this became hard since I can't easily filter them at my queries

I think all of them are instances of [Q18614948 - Wikidata property for authority control](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q18614948)

**I don't want to remove them, I need a way to identify them, like add a flag or a different label if wd has this class**

[SPARQL query:](https://query.wikidata.org/)

```
SELECT ?tipoLinguagem ?tipoLinguagemLabel
       ?subtipoLinguagem ?subtipoLinguagemLabel
       ?linguagem ?linguagemLabel
       ?wd ?wdLabel ?ps ?ps_Label ?wdpq ?wdpqLabel ?pq_ ?pq_Label
WHERE {

  ?tipoLinguagem wdt:P279 wd:Q629206 .
  ?subtipoLinguagem wdt:P279 ?tipoLinguagem .
  ?linguagem wdt:P31 ?subtipoLinguagem .

  ?linguagem ?p ?statement .
  ?statement ?ps ?ps_ .

  ?wd wikibase:claim ?p.
  ?wd wikibase:statementProperty ?ps.

  # NOT WORKINNG
  BIND(
    IF(?wd wdt:P31 wd:Q18614948)
    AS ?isIdentifier
  )

  OPTIONAL {
  ?statement ?pq ?pq_ .
  ?wdpq wikibase:qualifier ?pq .
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . } 

} ORDER BY ?linguagemLabel
```

[image: i]

Example of identifiers from [js entity page](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q2005):

[image]

Comment: Basically, you need something like `BIND ( EXISTS { ?wd wdt:P31 wd:Q18614948 } AS ?isIdentifier ) }` + some query optimization. However, properties might be identifiers not directly, i. e. you need `BIND ( EXISTS { ?wd wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q18614948 } AS ?isIdentifier ) `. Unfortunately, the latter is not working in Blazegraph. Use something like `{ BGP +  FILTER EXISTS { ?wd wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q18614948 }  BIND (true AS isIdentifier) } UNION  { BGP +  FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?wd wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q18614948 }  BIND (false AS isIdentifier) }`

Comment: Thanks, Stanislav. I'm not using Blazegraph, your code works

Comment: But Wikidata Query Service uses Blazegraph :-).